# Bash subsitution: Error if missing, remap if exists

Tags: bash

I want to do something like this, but in a clever way:

```
var=${1:?This is an error:+--arg ${1}}
```

This isn't valid syntax, but basically if someone passes `$1` as `foo` I want `var` to be `--arg foo` but if they don't, I want an error.

Is there a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need both tests, just use a plain assignment with the error test:

```
var="--arg ${1:?This is an error}"
```

If `$1` was passed, it assigns it (with the prefix "`--arg`") to the variable; if it wasn't passed, it prints the error and exits (hence no assignment happens).

BTW, It looks like you're trying to store multiple arguments (to some other program) in a plain variable. This isn't safe, because `$1` might contain spaces and/or wildcards, and if you refer to that variable without double-quotes (`someprogram $var`) it'll be split on all whitespace, and any wildcards will be expanded. On the other hand, if you double-quote it, the `--arg` part will be passed as part of the same argument.  Instead, use an array to store multiple values safely:

```
arrayvar=("--arg" "${1:?This is an error}")
someprogram "${arrayvar[@]}"
```

Comment: Excellent insight! Yeah, that's precisely what I am trying to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine multiple parameter expansion operators.

Do it in two steps. First check for error, then do the concatenation.

```
: ${1:?This is an error}
var="-arg $1"
```